# Passing data from Parent to Child via template

Tags: angular, angular2-template

I have a template user like following:

```
<div class="jumbotron">
  <div class="container">
    <h2><i class="fa fa-user"></i> {{username}}</h2>
    <p><i class="fa fa-star"></i> {{reputation}}</p>
  </div>
</div>
<app-list user={{username}}"></app-list>
```

My component for app-list looks like:

```
export class ListComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() user: string;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {   
    console.log(this.user);
  }  

}
```

The username and reputation is correctly shown on the page. However the username value is not passed correctly to the sub component app-list as it only print out an empty string.

How can I pass the username to the app-list component?

**Edit**

The user component looks like:

```
export class UserComponent implements OnInit {

  private username: string;
  private reputation: number;

  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute, private apiService: ApiService) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.route.params.subscribe((params: Params) => (
      this.apiService.getUser(params['username']).subscribe((response: Response) => {
          console.log(response.json());
          this.username = response.json().username;
          this.reputation = response.json().reputation;
        }, (error) => {
          if (error.status === 404) {
            // Todo: redirect to 404 page
          }
        }
      )
    ));
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be,

```
<app-list [user]="username"></app-list>
```

Comment: I have tried that too. The console just prints 'undefined'

Comment: it should work according to the code, do you see the username getting printed in user component

Comment: yes. the username and reputation is show on the user component.html. I just changed the code in the user component.ts so it doesn't load the data from the api and just directly assigns this.username = 'test' and like that the value is passed correctly to the list component. So the problem is from the subscribe call?

Comment: yeah! that would be he case, how does your apiService look like?

Comment: The component is @Injectable() and the method just `return this.http.get(host + username);`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148160/discussion-between-sajeetharan-and-isadon).

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively you can use `@ViewChild()` decorator to achieve the below

```
export class UserComponent implements OnInit {
 @ViewChild(AppListCopmonent) appList: AppListComponent;

  ngOnInit() {   
      this.appList.user = this.username
 }  
}
```

Update based on chat : Before assigning the value check if the data is there as

```
this.apiService.getUser(params['username']).subscribe((response: Response) => {      
  if(response){
      console.log(response.json());
      this.username = response.json().username;
      this.reputation = response.json().reputation;
    });
```

Comment: I am not sure how that would help. I am trying to send a value from parent to child. How would I access the value in the ListComponent?