# How can I access from a child component to another child component in Angular 4

Tags: angular, angular-components

I have a parent component and inside there are 2 different child components.
I need to call the second child component's function from the first child component when I click a link in the first child component.

So here is a basic diagram to explain better:

[image]

Comment: https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction

Comment: Custom Directive or Pipe is probably the right way here

Comment: Refer this [**answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44869853/passing-data-from-parent-to-child-via-template/44870116#44870116)

Comment: yes thanks, it is a very similar one.

Comment: Even though this is duplicate question but the answer is more accurate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could archieve this by means of `ViewChild` and `Output`

For example:

```js
@Component({
  template: `
     <child-one (clicked)="handleClick()"></child-one>
     <child-two></child-two>
  `
})
export class ParentComponent {
   @ViewChild(ChildOneComponent)
   childOne: ChildOneComponent;

   handleClick(){
    this.childOne.doSomething();
   }
}
```

In this case:

- `clicked` is an `Ouput` property of `ChildOneComponent`
- `doSomething` is a public method

Another approach only ussing `Output` and a template variable

```js
@Component({
  template: `
     <child-one (clicked)="childTwo.doSomething()"></child-one>
     <child-two #childTwo></child-two>
  `
})
export class ParentComponent {
   
}
```

Comment: thanks for this, actually right now I'm trying to do this. Once I finish I'll write again.

Comment: thanks, I finally managed with this way, also this one helped me too, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41954484/communicate-between-two-child-components-in-angular-2

Comment: another solution is using a service between these 2 components, this is also mentioned at above link

Comment: A service would be a better approach in the case that you want to exchange data between the components, and specially in the case that there is no parent-child relation. To just invoke a method, when an event is captured, this approach is ok