# accessing other components which are not children in Angular

Tags: angular

How can I access other components that are in the same view but aren't children? My parent component has some components.

**parent.component.html**

```
<html>
  <address-component></address-child>
  <name-component></name-component>
</html>
```

So how can I access `name-component` from the `address-component`? They do not have a relationship of their own except that they lie in the same view.

Comment: That depends on what it is you are trying to accomplish. Inter-component communication is not an end in itself.

Comment: I want to get the name component which is in the view and invoke a method with in the name component from the address component.

Comment: You could abstract the method responsible for creating the name into a service and inject that service into both components.

Comment: I know that.I am looking for ways not to do it since my detailed use case wont suit it.I am looking for ways within the component .something like access the form and get the name -component from within it or something like that.

Comment: Follow these already answered questions: 1. [First](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45170463/how-can-i-access-from-a-child-component-to-another-child-component-in-angular-4)
2. [Second](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41954484/communicate-between-two-child-components-in-angular-2)

Comment: Can you explain why what your use case is, and why a shared service doesn't suit?  Otherwise this just comes across as an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info)

Comment: `since my detailed use case wont suit` <= Then I recommend you provide a better / updated question with the details of what it is you are trying to accomplish. As it stands now your question is rather vague so in the event you do get an answer it will likely not answer your question.

Comment: You could pass the `name` component as an input parameter to the `address` component, as shown in [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-t6kv6c) (see the template in app.component.html).

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use a service, you can try this child1-parent-child2 communication:

```
<address-component (updateNameComponent)="nameComponent.yourMethodName()"></address-child>
<name-component #nameComponent ></name-component>
```

And in your address component, you would have this:

```
@Output() updateNameComponent = new EventEmitter();
```

and you can trigger nameComponent.yourMethodName from address component using this:

```
updateNameComponent.emit();
```